# Unions as a partial specialization of a templated base class

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

When I inherit from a templated base class that is a `union` and have partial specializations on it, the compilation on MSVC fails since it's forbidden to have `union`s as base classes (see 1).
If I however use a `struct` for the primary template I inherit from and only use `union` for the partial specializations it lets me compile it just fine.
I'm curious as to why that is. Also I'd like to know whether the below code (2) is standard compliant or MSVC only allowed me to get around the standard.

(1) C++ standard (10.4 Unions [class.union])

> "A union can have member functions (including constructors and
>   destructors), but it shall not have virtual (10.6.2) functions. A
>   union shall not have base classes. **A union shall not be used as a
>   base class**."

(2) Example ([godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/pMBZPV))

```
//template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
//↓             ↓   clearly illegal
//union vector_base {
//    vector_base() : data() {}
//    std::array<T, Size> data;
// }

template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
//↓ legal now?
struct vector_base
{
  std::array<T, Size> data;
};

template <typename T>
union vector_base<T, 2>
{
    std::array<T, 2> data;
    struct { T x, y; };
};

template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
class vector : public vector_base<T, Size> {
};
```

Comment: I think you have found a MSVS bug/"feature".  AFAIK you cannot specialize a template with a different class type (going from `struct` to `union`)  Both g++ and clang fail to compile: https://godbolt.org/g/3VDzPM

Comment: @NathanOliver: funny thing, g++ complains about something else here (partial specialization being a `union` instead of `struct`). If you pass `-fpermissive`, the code compiles (with a warning).

Comment: Do you really need `x` member instead of getter `T& x() { return data[0]; }` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is not legal. From [[temp.class]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class#4):

> In a redeclaration, partial specialization, explicit specialization or explicit instantiation of a class template, the class-key shall agree in kind with the original class template declaration ([[dcl.type.elab]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab)).

A [class-key](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#nt:class-key) is one of `class`, `struct`, or `union`.

In your case, your partial specialization is illegal, since you use a class-key of `union` when you previously used `struct`.

---

To get the behavior you want, use an [anonymous union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union#Anonymous_unions) inside the class:

```
template <typename T>
struct vector_base<T, 2>
{
    union {
        std::array<T, 2> data;
        // Note that anonymous structs are non-standard, but supported in C11
        struct { T x, y; };
    };
};
```

However, be careful of this `union`; you may be tempted to access the inactive member, but that's [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11996970/1896169) unless the union members share a [common initial sequence](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#def:common_initial_sequence). I'm not sure in this case if they do, but I think they do not, since `std::array` is a distinct type from `T[2]`, and I'm not even sure if `T[2]` and `T x, y` would be a common initial sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Your partial specialization is **not** a `union`.

As you point out, `union` cannot be used as a base class, and as [Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51680469/8964493) points out, using `union` keyword for partial specialization is not legal.

Adding to this: for some reason MSVC doesn't mind use of `union` keyword and simply ignores class key of the partial specialization and treats it as a definition of `struct`.

The same thing happens in case of `gcc`. It complains about different class-key, but once you pass `-fpermissive` flag to the compiler, your example compiles, although `vector<T, 2>` is a structure, not a union.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/1Nfnmr)

Comment: I guess they should really add a warning here at least.